# React gives me Cannot GET / page_name While reloading (node/express)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to build a `reactjs` app and I am trying to pass data through from my front end (react) to my backend (node/express). However I am getting an **error** when I try and view the page I get this error. (Cannot GET /home).

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
  })
);


app.post("/home", (req, res) => {
  const data = [(generalDetail = req.body.generalDetail)];
  console.log(generalDetail, "has been added to /home");

  res.json(data);
});

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

**here is my `onSubmit` function:**

```
onSubmitForm = e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          let data = {
                generalDetail: this.state.generalDetails,
                firstName: this.state.firstName,
                middleName: this.state.middleName,
                lastName: this.state.lastName
          };

          axios.post("http://localhost:5000/home", data).then(() => {
             //do something
           }).catch(() => {
              console.log("Something went wrong. Plase try again later");

          });
```

Comment: Have you tried testing this route on Postman?

Comment: did u try adding the below code above the post route.

    app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
      console.log("here");
    });

Comment: You don't have a handler for GET /home route. I can only see POST /home.
If you go to http://localhost:5000/home in your browser then you get the error because browser makes a GET request not the POST.

Comment: @Molda could you please show me how to do a handler for a GET /home route?

Comment: app.get("/home", (req, res) => { 
   console.log("you are in the home route")
})

Comment: You are missing definition for /home in GET verb, which is the verb which will be called when you try to access the /home URL from browser directly, just like @Molda explained.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a get route for home, that is why you are having trouble.
Add the following code above your post route.

```
app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
    console.log("here"); 
});
```